LilyPond - Put ALL noteheads to the left of stems, regardless of stem direction
I handwrote this score a while ago I'm trying to transcribe.

You can see that all the noteheads are to the left of the stems, regardless of which way the stem is pointing.  Lots of old handwritten manuscripts have this, but I want the effect on purpose so I can use one cross-staff stem to connect simultaneous notes on the top and bottom staves, align the notes horizontally, and put the beam in between the staves.
I've been trying to transcribe this in LilyPond, but I'm running into great difficulty doing two things:

Putting all the noteheads to the left of the stems, regardless of stem direction
Creating a cross-staff beam in between the staves (or allowing two beams from opposite staves to collide)


Anyone have an idea how to do this?  The closest I've come is this:

Include the Span_stem_engraver in the GrandStaff Context
Set both staves to \stemUp
Enclose the bottom staff in a \crossStaff block
Beam the bottom staff and not the top staff
Put \override Stem.length = 0 in the top staff

This gives a basically correct rendering for the excerpt I've shown, but it has two problems:

It doesn't work if there is a note in the top staff but a rest in the bottom staff, because the beam and the cross-staff stem don't extend properly in that event.
It puts a tiny extra bit of stem length next to the noteheads in the top staff.

Picture:

Does anyone have a better idea on how I can do this?

@CarlWitthoft Lilypond is correct.  I tried to put [Lilypond] at the start of my description, but the automod thingy said to delete it and just use a regular tag instead (which I did).

@DWW256 While adding proper tags is correct, also mentioning the software in the title (you don't need square brackets, just put it in the context of the phrase) or, at least, the question body is always better. In any case, your query is a bit controversial. Can you please [edit] and improve your post by explaining exactly why do you want to do that? I've seen such attempts in the past, and even if they were somehow "justified" by their authors, that notation is quite awkward and normally needed for very specific (and, frankly, extremely well motivated, which I haven't seen so far) cases.

"Lots of old handwritten manuscripts have this": some old engraved scores, too.  I wonder whether the practice of inverting arose from the use of movable type.  On second thought, probably not, but still.  I particularly associate the "backward" stem position with English publications, probably late 18th to early 19th century, but I may be remembering incorrectly.

@musicamante please read this. This is the semi-official policy of whole Stack Exchange. Perhaps on some sites having duplicate tags is accepted and won't be challenged as much, however "is always better" is just wrong.

@musicamante sorry, but no, I don't think we should ask users to repeat tags in the comments. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399209/should-we-repeat-tags-in-question-title and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles I know I should have posted on Music Meta rather than Main SE – that was by accident, sorry. We can open a discussion post on Music Meta, if y'all think there are special cases on this site.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda Fair, "always better" is not appropriate. Still, it's not bad to explicit it in the title or the body: due to their visual hint/placement, tags are not immediately seen, and checking them is not automatic for everybody. I agree that repeating them everywhere is redundant, but since the post body (even more than the title) is the part that's normally read first, only mentioning the "subject" in the tag is a bit questionable too: I sometimes open many posts at once from the home, where tags are more visible, but once I've read a few I may have already forgot about them.

@DWW256 Are you completely sure about that notation choice? Even imagining your handwritten example as properly engraved, I'd find that distracting and confusing. The issue is not really about the notehead position, but the common beam for both upper/lower notes and multiple bars. Is this intended for a single player (possibly a percussion set)? If you do want to share the same stems, maybe a better choice would be to just put the beams on top or bottom, but I still don't see the need to use just one single beam.

The two staves are for one person.  I felt like using one beam reduced the visual noise on the page—and for the record, I did find it readable enough when I played it.
Also complicating things is that there's another grand staff above this one, so I wanted to avoid piling up beams outside of the grand staff.

@musicamante would you like to comment on https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4041/should-we-repeat-tags-in-question-title

@DWW256 Maybe you found it readable because you wrote it ;-) Another issue is that that long, middle beam becomes a bit "mixed up" with the staff lines, especially considering that you're using 3-lines staves: interestingly enough, the image in Elements' answer shows that beam exactly in the middle of the two staves, and the fact that it's thicker is marginal. I understand that you want to avoid an overcrowded layout, but sometimes it's better to be explicit and verbose. You're already adding extra space between those staves (possibly to avoid the line confusion above), so, why don't you »

@DWW256 » add that extra space above the top stave? Or, as written before, just use one common beam at the bottom. Consider that "writing less" is not always for the better. Musicians are used to crowded parts, and reading a "noisy" part that still uses standard notation is normally better than a "cleaner" one using an uncommon one. If that's intended for percussion, there should be no problem for the player: we're used to two-staves parts, and using separated beams for top/bottom isn't "noisy": if the writing is consistent, the player will instantly see that they're simultaneous.

In this case, it might be easier to not use \ crossStaff / Span_stem_engraver.
For the upper staff, instead of setting the stems up and making them have zero length, set the stems down, and move them with offsets and an extra-offset.
Manually beam the semiquavers (in both staffs) with brackets, and then make the beam in the upper staff transparent.
For the lower staff, set the beam positions.
\version "2.24.1"

\new GrandStaff {
    \override Score.TimeSignature.stencil = ##f
    <<
        \new DrumStaff {
            \override DrumStaff.StaffSymbol.line-positions = #'(4 0 -4)
            
            \clef "varpercussion"
            
            \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
            
            \stemDown
            \override Stem.X-offset = #1.25
            \override Stem.Y-offset = #1.5
            \override Stem.extra-offset = #'(0 . -1.5)
            
            \override Beam.transparent = ##t
            
            \drummode {
                tomfl8[ r8 tomml8 tomml8 r8 tomfl8 r8 tomml8 |
                \bar "!"
                r8 tomfl8 tomml8 r8 tomh8 r8 r8 r8] |
            }
        }
        \new DrumStaff {
            \override DrumStaff.StaffSymbol.line-positions = #'(4 0 -4)
            
            \clef "varpercussion"
            
            \override NoteHead.style = #'cross
            
            \stemUp
            
            \override Beam.positions = #'(4.5 . 4.5)
            
            \drummode {
                tomfl8[ r8 tomml8 tomml8 r8 tomfl8 r8 tomml8 |
                
                r8 tomfl8 tomml8 r8 tomh8 r8 r8 r8] |
            }
        }
    >>
}


